# EF two one to many relations, something get wrong

Tags: entity-framework

What I trying to do:

I have entity named 'Department', and each department might have several translations to different languages (e.g. "Sales" on English, "Sales" on German, etc).

Also, each 'Department' could have synonyms in either language.

I want to make number of available translations and synonyms flexible as possible, since I don't know ahead how much translations or synonyms I will have for each department.

Therefore, my idea was to do something like this:

```
public class DepartmentEntity
{
    public Departments Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public List<DepartmentNaming> Names
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public List<DepartmentNaming> Synonyms
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}


public class DepartmentNaming
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual DepartmentEntity Department { get; set; }

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Language Language
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

This results in some kind of bizarre table, where I have the following columns:

```
[Id]                   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Name]                 NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Language]             INT            NOT NULL,
[Department_Id]        INT            NULL,
[DepartmentEntity_Id]  INT            NULL,
[DepartmentEntity_Id1] INT            NULL,
```

Basically, I see this as a one-to-many relation, since one particular department can have many translations, and one particular translation belongs to one specific department (same for synonyms).

So - why it creates DepartmentEntity_Id and DepartmentEntity_Id1 for me? What do I miss? Probably I need somehow to tell EF about what I want to achieve, but I don't know how...

Thanks

Comment: when you referenced DepartmentName as Names and Synonyms in Department Entity, EF will translate them to 1 to many relation which appears as a result and also when you referenced Department inside your DepartmentName, it will be foreignkey, some more explanation might let us to help you more, do you mean that the DepartmentName can be either Name or synonyms ? this what you want to achieve?

Comment: @HadiHassan: Exactly. DepartmentName can be either Name or Synonym.

Comment: so you don't need to reference them both in the DepartmentEntity, instead add another entity called DepartmentType and reference it in the DepartmentName entiry, where DepartmentType contains [ Id,Name] Name="Name" or Name="Synonym", if you want some code, I can add it as answer

Answer (score 1):

As I understood from your question and your comment, Name, Synonym are types for the DepartmentName

no need to reference the DepartmentName inside the DepartmentEntity.

below is the design that might help you in your implementation, you can rename the classes in the way to match yours

```
// this will hold the defualt department names
public class Department
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
}

// this will hold the translation type: name or synonym
public class TranslationType
{
    public int Id{get; set;}
    public string Name{get; set;}
}
// this will hold the translation language name: en,gr...
public class Language
{
    public int Id{get; set;}
    public string Name{get; set;}
}

// this will hold the translated name and its type as synonym or name
public class Translation
{
    public int Id{get; set;}
    public string Name{get; set;}
    public int LanguageId{get; set;}
    public int TranslationTypeId{get;set;}

    public Language Language{get; set;}
    public TranslationType TranslationType{get; set;}
}

// this will be many to many relation to link departments to its translated languages
public class DepartmentTranslation
{       
    public Department Department{get; set;}
    public Translation Translation{get; set;}
}
```

hope this will help you

Comment: That not exactly what I looked for, but you gave me idea how to resolve my issue. Thank you